# Call Javascript from GridView TemplateField

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a GridView, I have coded like the below

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item">
 <ItemTemplate>                                            
   <asp:Button ID="btnItem" OnClientClick="javascript:SearchReqsult(<%#Eval("Id") %>);"
 CssClass="Save" runat="server" /> 
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I face a run time error which says that my button control is formatted correctly
I suppose the issue with the following

```
OnClientClick="javascript:SearchReqsult(<%#Eval("Id") %>);"
```

Any idea?

Comment: try to use this OnClientClick="javascript:SearchReqsult('<%# Eval("Id") %>');"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
    { 
         Button btn = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnItem");
         btn.Attributes.Add("OnClick","SearchReqsult(this.id);");
    } 
 }
```

Comment: ID is the field to bound with button.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do this is databound. Maybe something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    yourGridView.RowDataBound += (s, ev) =>
            {
               if (ev.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
               {
                   var btn= (Button) ev.Row.FindControl("btnCheque");
                   btn.OnClientClick = "javascript:SearchReqsult(" + 
                                     DataBinder.Eval(ev.Row.DataItem, "Id") + ");";
               }
            };
}
```

Comment: I do update panel post back using __doPostBack inside javascript:SearchReqsult. But Request.Params.Get("__EVENTARGUMENT") is always null when I click on the button. the ID doesnt get passed code behind

Answer (score 1):

Try enclosing javascript function call in single quotes:

`OnClientClick='javascript:SearchReqsult(<%#Eval("Id") %>);'`

Maybe the problem is with missing/wrong quotes.

Comment: This is not rendering the onclick event of properly. Please check your view source of your page.

Answer (score 1):

> Try with String.Format Class

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCheque" runat="server" 
OnClientClick=<%#String.Format("return SearchReqsult('{0}');", Eval("ID")) %> />
```

Answer (score 1):

Enclose your 'id' field in single quotes.

just replace

```
 btn.OnClientClick = "javascript:SearchReqsult(" + 
                                 DataBinder.Eval(ev.Row.DataItem, "Id") + ");";
```

with

```
 btn.OnClientClick = "javascript:SearchReqsult(" + 
                                 DataBinder.Eval(ev.Row.DataItem, 'Id') + ");";
```

your code will come as

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
yourGridView.RowDataBound += (s, ev) =>
        {
           if (ev.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
           {
               var btn= (Button) ev.Row.FindControl("btnCheque");
               btn.OnClientClick = "javascript:SearchReqsult(" + 
                                 DataBinder.Eval(ev.Row.DataItem, 'Id') + ");";
           }
        };
}
```

Comment: We can directly move Your above mentioned code to HTML side only.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to do

CODE BEHIND:

```
protected void GridView_RowCreated(object sender,GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem) !=null)
            ((Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnCheque")).Attributes.Add("onclick","SearchReqsult(" + ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["productId"].ToString() + ")");

    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCheque" CssClass="Save" runat="server" Text="My Button" />
```

Comment: Change "productId" column name to your column name "id". This is a working code example.

Comment: Your lazy loading is wrong in this context. `DataRowView` cannot be null.. Instead you can check `((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["Id"]` for null values.

Comment: Why you should go for code behind for such a small task? Just need to call the client function on button click. So no need to waste execution time in executing code behind as well...

Comment: @PankajGarg `DataRowView` can be null on post back. Have a look.

Comment: DataRowView cannot be null. Reason is, the datasource suppose offers you 10 row, this means that you have view of 10 rows. So itself row cannot be null. **BUT** the cell value can be null. If row is null, then what are you expecting from your `DataSource` ?  If you are expecting no rows then it will not come to `RowboundData` for `DataItem` iteration.

Comment: @PankajGarg did you try? add the code and press the button. replace **SearchReqsult** to an alert and put a break point at GridView_RowCreated method. Let me know after that.

Comment: Why to add the code in Code Behind for such a short operation? Is it really required ? Is it fine to just add it in merely HTML side?

Answer (score 0):

Put Labe l and bind Id in that and make it visible false.

On GridView RowDatabound event add attrinute to control and assign javascript on button onclientclick event

Answer (score 0):

Try with single quotes instead of double and string.Format()

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCheque" OnClientClick=<%# string.Format("javascript:SearchReqsult('{0}');return false;",Eval("id")) %> CssClass="Save" runat="server" />
```

Comment: This is not rendering the onclick event properly. Please check the View source in your page.

Comment: I have updated the code. This should work. Please remove the retun false; if you dont need.

Comment: Still there is one formatting issue. Single quote is missing around the {0} and single quote not required before your <%#

Answer (score 0):

Call javascript function from Template Field

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" OnClientClick=<%#String.Format("return dis_status('{0}');", Eval("Status")) %> runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("AgtId")%>' Text='<%# Eval("Status")%>' CommandName="cmdDelete" />
</ItemTemplate>
```